# Magento 2 - display and hidden column grid by permission

Tags: magento2

I added a new column to product grid on back-office Magento, but I want to display it where the role is " admin " and hide it if not.

I add the column using this code :

```
<column name="user_id">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">User</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

Comment: Did you have a created custom module for adding a new column?

Comment: @KamleshSolanki yes sir

Comment: Then you have to create acl.xml for your module and given custom permission for a particulre user from the backend.

Comment: @KamleshSolanki I have an ACL, but I added a new column to product grid, so, I need to add permission just to it, and hide it when the role is not `Admin`

Comment: But it is not possible to given particular column permission in Magento. But I am not sure it is possible or not

Comment: @KamleshSolanki, is there any method to create a column using PHP, here I can add a role verification

Comment: I found this code on XML `<item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>` to hide OR display the column, is there any method to change to value of it using PHP ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To help more people to fix this problem I will share the solution :

first, you need to add this code to your ui_componenet XML file

```
<item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
```

after you will create a file on NAMESPACE/MODULE/Ui/Listing/Columns/yourfile.php with this code :

```
public function prepare()
    {
        parent::prepare();
        if (YOUR_CONDITION) { 
            $this->_data['config']['componentDisabled'] = false;
        }
    }
```